# sort array by object attributes

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, laravel-5

I want to sort a array containing objects as follows:

```
$object = new object();
$object->time = "10:30";
$object2 = new object();
$object2->time = "9:30";
$array = array($object, $object2);
```

What is the most efficient way to organize the array so that the first object is the earliest time??

Thanks for help.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/3933332 you probably want to use `usort()`

Comment: $object = new object();
$object->time = "10:30";
$object2 = new object();
$object2->time = "9:30";
$array = array($object, $object2);

$collection = collect($array);
$collection->orderBy('time','ASC');